# App crashes with empty float edittext

Tags: java, toast

need help on this! 
Im trying to make toast for a empty edittext, and turns out keep getting errors with the float.

Please advise

This is the code:

```
  calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


   **float bs = Float.parseFloat(basicSalary.getText().toString());**
     float tw = Float.parseFloat(totalAllowance.getText().toString());
     float mob = String spinTEXT = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

if (spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Select age group")){
         Toast.makeText(sghospitalbonuscalculator.this, "Test 123",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

if (basicSalary.getText().toString().equals("")){
         Toast.makeText(sghospitalbonuscalculator.this, "Test 321",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:308)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
at sg.self.wser.bonuscalc.bonuscalcu$4.onClick(bonuscalcu.java:96)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

> The bonuscalc.java:96 is referring to this line of code:
>
> float bs = Float.parseFloat(basicSalary.getText().toString());

As for the toast, i tried to change the .equals("") to .equals(" "), .equals(null) and .isEmpty, but still it wouldnt work.

Please advise! 
Thanks a million!

Edited version:

Code:

```
  if (basicSalary.getText().toString().equals(0.0)){
          Toast.makeText(sghospitalbonuscalculator.this, "Test 321",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Errors shown:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
```

Comment: what float number do you think that an empty space represents?

Comment: hmmmmmmm 0.0f? Apologize if im wrong, please enlighten me!

Comment: **wrong** `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""`

Comment: meaning its not a float ?

Comment: That's right `""` is not a float

Comment: hmmm okie thank you I understand, but still I have tried putting 0.0, 0.0f but still getting errors.

Comment: Please update your code so that we can see what you have done.

Comment: I updated my code with the edited version below, thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test if your input is blank and if so assign the value 0.0

```
float bs = 0.0f;
if (basicSalary.getText().toString().equals("") == false){
      bs = Float.parseFloat(basicSalary.getText().toString());
}
```

further down you test this for the `Toast`

```
if (basicSalary.getText().toString().equals("")){
         Toast.makeText(sghospitalbonuscalculator.this, "Test 321",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

maybe you could change it to

```
if (bs == 0.0f){
         Toast.makeText(sghospitalbonuscalculator.this, "Test 321",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: `float bs = 0.0f;`    

 this code is assigning 0.0f value to bs 

`if (basicSalary.getText().toString().equals("") == false){
      bs = Float.parseFloat(basicSalary.getText().toString());
}`   this code is saying that if the content of the basicSalary edittext box is not empty, set bs to float content of basicSalary. 



Am i right?

Comment: It is saying 1) set a default value of 0.0 to bs  2) if `basicSalary` is not blank, convert its value to a float and set bs to this value.

Comment: Understand completely!!!! Seriously thank you very much! pardon me for my noob question, as I really stuck with this for 3 days and with my poor knowledge in Java I feel that im reallly did my best before posting! 
Thank you once again! 
I LOVE JAVA! wooohooo!